# Disable button until you have x amount of item in cart?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

so i have a store and it has several steps to buy something,each step presents the user with a diferent kind of product, lets say Juices and they have to choose what juices they want, and i want to disable the button that takes the user to the next step until there is x amount of the item of the first step in the cart

this is my button

```
<form action="http://examplesite.com/step-2/">&nbsp;

<input id= "btnBox" type="submit" value="next step" align="right" />
```

in the step one page(the one the button is located on in this case) the user has to add 2 of the item to the cart, and i want to disable the next step button until the user has added those two items

possible useful info:

i am using porto as the theme

WooCommerce Max Quantity is being used

and this is what i validate now when adding an item to the cart

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, 
$variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) 
{

global $woocommerce;
$cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();


if ( $quantity >2 && ($product_id == an item id or $product_id == an item id )){
  $passed = false;
  wc_add_notice( __( 'Maximum of 2 items', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
}
if($quantity >1 && ($product_id ==an item id or $product_id == an item id or $product_id == an item id or $product_id == an item id))
{
    $passed = false;
    wc_add_notice( __( 'maximum of 1 item', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
}





return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 
'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Do you know how to check how many items are in the cart?

Comment: **The question is unclear**: What kind of multi step? products based or checkout based? Where is it located? Is it a custom template? What other customizations are involved? The code in your question is too minimal and there is very few details. That might not give you useful answers as nobody can guess.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i do, but i am not sure about checking how many of an specific item there is

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Sorry about that, i dont know much about it and i am still trying to figure out, i will explain a bit more in a bit in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using PHP code snippets (Insert PHP) plugin to write the code to do it

```
global $woocommerce;    
$targeted_id = an id;
$qty = 0;



foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) 
{ 
if($cart_item['product_id'] == $targeted_id )
{
    $qty =  $cart_item['quantity'];
    break;
    }         

}

if ( $qty == 0 )
{  
 ?> 

     <form action="asite.com/" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="next" 
     name="Submit" id="next" disabled/>
     </form>
     <?php  

}
else
{
 ?>   
      <form action="asite.com/" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="next" 
     name="Submit" id="next" />
     </form> 
     <?php

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener to watchout for change and add the disabled validation inside this function, please refer my below example!

**Note:** I use the `+` operator before the `$("#cart").val()` so that the extracted value which is of type `string` will be converted to `number`.

```js
function checkQuantity() {
  var quantity = +$("#cart").val();
  var next = $("#btnBox");
  if (quantity >= 2) {
    next.removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    next.attr("disabled", "true");

  }
}
$("#cart").on("change", checkQuantity);
checkQuantity();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://examplesite.com/step-2/">&nbsp;
  <input id="cart" type="number" />
  <input id="btnBox" type="submit" value="next step" align="right" />
</form>
```

Comment: sorry for the ignorance but the #cart is a generic name for my woocommerce cart? because i am getting an unexpected var, i am putting the function right on the functions.php

Comment: @leonidas56 I need to look at the website checkout page, also I need to know which element needs to be checked for quantity and which button to close, if you could give an image also, I will check!

Comment: hey here are screenshot of both pages, and as for what items i have to check for its the quantity of certain items, depending on id, lets say id = 300, here you can see both screens and in the first one is the button i need to disable https://imgur.com/a/ciEDptE both images have a link to their page, thank you for the help

Comment: @leonidas56 So the quantity will change based on the product is it? then we have a complicated scenario!

Comment: but there are only 6 possible products (two with quantity required 2 and four with quantity required 1 )

Comment: also since there is only 6 possible products (and there will always be since they are based in categories) i was thinking about making a single function for each  

this is something i did for one

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hsP5BHb

the problem is that disables it anyway, even if add a product into the cart and reload the page it still stays disabled,